# Deploying Meteor App on AWS EC2 using mup. Browser returns: 'took too long to respond'

Tags: amazon-web-services, meteor, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to deploy a Meteor app using mup and an AWS EC2 micro instance.

I've followed the whole tutorial here http://www.curtismlarson.com/blog/2015/11/03/deploy-meteor-to-aws/, successfully running `mup deploy`.

However when I go to the instance's Public IP on google chrome or firefox, it simply says:

> myapp.com took too long to respond.

If anyone could tell me how I can find the source of this problem, I'd be extremely grateful!

Here's my `mup.json`:

```
{
  // Server authentication info
  "servers": [
    {
      "host": "52.***.***.***",
      "username": "ubuntu",
      "pem": "~/************.pem"
    }
  ],

  // Install MongoDB in the server, does not destroy local MongoDB on future setup
  "setupMongo": true,

  // WARNING: Node.js is required! Only skip if you already have Node.js installed on server.
  "setupNode": true,

  // WARNING: If nodeVersion omitted will setup 0.10.36 by default. Do not use v, only version number.
  "nodeVersion": "0.10.41",

  // Install PhantomJS in the server
  "setupPhantom": true,

  // Show a progress bar during the upload of the bundle to the server.
  // Might cause an error in some rare cases if set to true, for instance in Shippable CI
  "enableUploadProgressBar": true,

  // Application name (No spaces)
  "appName": "menus",

  // Location of app (local directory)
  "app": "~/menus",

  // Configure environment
  "env": {
    "ROOT_URL": "http://myapp.com"
  },

  // Meteor Up checks if the app comes online just after the deployment
  // before mup checks that, it will wait for no. of seconds configured below
  "deployCheckWaitTime": 15
}
```

The `"ROOT_URL": "http://myapp.com"` line is exactly how it appears in the file ( I didn't know what else to choose).

**Edit: Here's the `/opt/menus/config/env.sh` file:**

```
#!/bin/bash
export PORT=80
export MONGO_URL=mongodb://127.0.0.1/menus
export ROOT_URL=http://localhost

#it is possible to override above env-vars from the user-provided values

  export PORT=\8\0

  export ROOT_URL=\h\t\t\p\:\/\/\m\y\a\p\p\.\c\o\m

  export METEOR_SETTINGS=\{\"\p\u\b\l\i\c\"\:\{\}\}

  export CLUSTER_ENDPOINT_URL=\h\t\t\p\:\/\/\5\2\.\2\0\1\.\2\1\2\.\1\4\2\:\8\0
```

Those escapes definitely look out of place, but I feel like 1 wrong stroke could leave it still crashing! The fact that `ROOT_URL` is defined twice is concerning me. How exactly should I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

For me `mup` still has a bug where the file `/opt/myapp/config/env.sh` generated by `mup` was incorrectly formatted (there were some extra spaces and extra escapes). You may want to check that, i.e., ssh into your instance and look at that file. If you need to fix it, do so, and then run `mup restart` from your development machine.

The second hypothesis I have is that `mup` doesn't interpret `~`. So you may want to try using the resolved path for `app`, or just the relative path from where your mup.json lives.

**Update:**

As expected, the env.sh file is wrong (bug in mup). Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
export PORT=80
export MONGO_URL=mongodb://127.0.0.1/menus
export ROOT_URL=http://localhost

#it is possible to override above env-vars from the user-provided values

export PORT=80
export ROOT_URL="http://myapp.com"
export METEOR_SETTINGS="{\"public\":{}}"
export CLUSTER_ENDPOINT_URL="http://52.201.212.142:80"
```

Comment: I've put the code from `opt/myapp/config/env.sh` into the question: could you give me a hand in editing it?

Comment: great! now it's easy to tell that that is indeed the problem (or at least part of it!).

Comment: Alright! I tried your suggestion; I fiddled with it a bit and after removing the "" marks around the `ROOT_URL` etc at the bottom of your suggestion (to make them consistent with the top), I get no errors from `mup logs`. However, my browser is still timing out! (or taking a very very long time?)